# UI fuera de los margenes de la pantalla, jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, app, jetpack-compose

soy un principiante en el desarrollo de apps en android, estoy diseñando una UI en jetpack compose. Mi problema es el siguiente, la mitad de mi layout esta fuera de los margenes de la pantalla y no se como solucionarlo. El diseño debe encajar en la pantalla entera, no scrolling.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como deberia verse:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Codigo:

```
@Composable
fun ObraYArtista(modifier: Modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color.White)) {

    Box(modifier.wrapContentSize()
        .padding(50.dp)) {

        Column(modifier.padding(20.dp)) {

            Surface(shadowElevation = 10.dp) {

                Image(painter = painterResource(id =R.drawable.randomchica ),
                    contentDescription = null,
                )
            }

            Spacer(modifier.height(100.dp))

            Box(
                modifier
                    .background(color = Color.LightGray)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(bottom = 20.dp)
                    .padding(horizontal = 6.dp)
            ) {

                Column() {
                    Text(text = "Chica mirando a la izquierda",
                        fontSize = 23.sp,
                        fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Light
                    )

                    Text(text = "~Lucas Galeano",
                        fontSize = 16.sp)
                }

            }
            Spacer(modifier.height(10.dp))
            Buttons()
        }
    }
}
```